# Using PCA in R--Changing axes to remove columns

Tags: r, pca

I have the following code in R.  Briefly, I start with the iris data from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data .
Then I want to perform principal component analysis on this dataset to end up with a two dimensional dataset that I can at the end make a scatterplot of the final data. I'm using the prcomp function to get the principal component, and taking the rotation from that.

```
irisdat <- read.csv('iris.data', header=FALSE)
library(lattice)
library(stats)
numiris=irisdat[,c(1,2,3,4)]
pr=prcomp(numiris, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
newdata = as.matrix(numiris) %*% pr$rotation
pr2=prcomp(newdata, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
newdata2 = as.matrix(newdata) %*% pr2$rotation
```

Now the problem that I have is that I just end up with a matrix that still has four dimensions when I want to get it down to two by the end but I'm not sure how to remove columns, or what to remove, after doing the principal component analysis projection.

Also, I'm having a problem where my results are inverted from the original data so if I print out a scatterplot matrix with splom, the scatterplots are reversed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you need help or statistical advice on performing a PCA analysis, then you should be asking over at [stats.se]. That's not a specific programming question. Please ask one clear question at a time. Also it probably would be easier for your example if you used the built-in `iris` dataset rather than requiring a separate download to run your example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly unclear on what you're asking... but I'll give it a shot.

PCA in and of itself will not remove columns; in most cases, you'll end up with the same number of components as there are features. The difference is that each of the principal components is a linear combination of the input features and is orthogonal (and thus uncorrelated) to each of the other components. The components are arranged descending by variability explained. One typically retains the first N components which cumulatively explain ~70% of the variability. You can get the 
percentage of explained variance like this:

```
numiris = iris[,1:4] ## iris is built-in
pr = prcomp(numiris, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
> cumsum(pr$sdev^2 / sum(pr$sdev^2))
[1] 0.7296245 0.9581321 0.9948213 1.0000000
```

Thus, you'd retain the first component in your case:

```
reduced = as.matrix(pr$rotation[,1])
```

However, if you're absolutely set on retaining two:

```
reduced = as.matrix(pr$rotation[,1:2])
```

Additionally, you can plot the `prcomp` object using `screeplot`.

Answer (score -1):

Some methods (such as `irlba`) allow you to specify a number of returned vectors.  Otherwise, you can probably take advantage of the fact that returned columns are of decreasing significance from left to right.  Try using `newdata[,1:2]`.  And MrFlick is right, the `iris` dataset is built in to R.